# How to save changes and installed packages so I can install them in other systems

Tags: installation, apt, dpkg

I want to format my system, but I don’t want to lose my updates and installed packages. I also want the same packages on other systems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up should be:

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/sources.list
sudo apt-key exportall > ~/Repo.keys
```

and restoring should be

```
sudo apt-key add ~/Repo.keys
sudo cp ~/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dselect
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y
```

...If I'm not mistaken.